# how to add a icon in antd cascader children options' label

Tags: ant-design-pro

i want to add a icon to children's label. and it can be clicked for edit something.

antd version : 3.9.2

```
const options = [{
    value: 'zhejiang',
    label: 'Zhejiang',
    children: [{
        value: 'hangzhou',
        label: 'Hangzhou'
    }],
}, {
    value: 'jiangsu',
    label: 'Jiangsu',
    children: [{
        value: 'nanjing',
        label: 'Nanjing',
    }],
}];

class Demo extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Cascader 
                options={options}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a classname to cascader and add css

```
 .iconImage{
         background-image: url('../assets/images/triangle.png');
         background-size: 100% 100%;
         background-color: transparent;
         color:transparent;
        }
```